# How to reverse and make a string from the array in JavaScript with comma separated and space array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

My array is **:** `var array1 = ['c', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'e', 'a', 't', ' ', 'I'];`

Output expected is **:** `I eat cake`

How I can do that using JavaScript ?

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for? if so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `join` to concate all of the chars in an array, then use `split` to separate them by " ". now, you can reverse that array of strings and join them once again by " ".

```js
var s = ['c','a','k','e',' ', 'e','a','t',' ','I'];

var str = s.join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Most welcome @sagarkumbhar - would appreciate if you can accept the answer if you're satisfied with the answer?